# dynamically create list of data frames from csv files

Tags: r, list, csv, dataframe, hashtable

I want to read many csv files at once to one big hash like structure where under the key (which will be the name of csv file) the particular dataset will be accessible. AFAIK R does not have hashes so the choice was to use lists with named elements (if this is not correct approach correct me please). My code so far:

```
csv_files <- list.files(pattern="*.csv");
datasets  <- vector("list", length(csv_files));
names(datasets) <- csv_files;

for (i in 1:length(datasets)){
  csv_file <- names(datasets[i])
  datasets[i] <- read.csv(file=csv_file, header=T, sep=",", skip=0, check.names=TRUE)
}
```

But this code does not work (`datasets` contains something other but not particular csv data.frame) and returns following warning:

```
Warning messages:
1: In datasets[i] <- read.csv(file = csv_file, header = T, sep = ",",  :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
2: In datasets[i] <- read.csv(file = csv_file, header = T, sep = ",",  :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
3: In datasets[i] <- read.csv(file = csv_file, header = T, sep = ",",  :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
4: In datasets[i] <- read.csv(file = csv_file, header = T, sep = ",",  :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
5: In datasets[i] <- read.csv(file = csv_file, header = T, sep = ",",  :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Here are results of my troubleshooting:

Seems that reading from csv file is working:

```
> csv_file <- names(datasets[1])
> temp_dataset <- read.csv(file=csv_file, header=T, sep=",", skip=0, check.names=TRUE)
> temp_dataset
   ord orig pred as o.p
1    1    0    0  1   0
2    2    0    0  1   0
3    3    0    0  1   0
4    4    0    0  0   0
5    5    0    0  0   0
6    6    0    0  0   0
7    7    0    0  0   0
8    8    0    0  0   0
9    9    0    0  0   0
10  10    0    0  0   0
11  11    0    0  0   0
12  12    0    0  0   0
13  13    0    0  0   0
14  14    0    0  0   0
15  15    0    0  0   0
16  16    0    0  0   0
17  17    0    0  0   0
18  18    0    0  0   0
19  19    0    0  0   0
20  20    0    0  0   0
21  21    0    0  0   0
22  22    0    0  0   0
23  23    4    0  0   4
24  24  402    0  1 402
25  25    0    0  1   0
26  26    0    0  1   0
27  27    0    0  1   0
28  28    1    0  1   0
```

Problem is with assigning those data to particular data frame inside list

```
> datasets[1] <- temp_dataset[-1]
Warning message:
In datasets[1] <- temp_dataset[-1] :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Seems that only first column is assigned to particular data frame inside list:

```
> datasets[1]
$repeating.csv
repeating.csv
 [1]   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
[17]   0   0   0   0   0   0   4 402   0   0   0   1
```

What I'm missing?

Comment: Try `datasets[[i]] <- ...` And why use the line `csv_file <- names(datasets[i])`?  Instead try `file = csv_files[i]` in `read.csv`

Comment: If you want to read all the files into a list of data frames, you could do `sapply(csv_files, read.csv)`. The name of each list element will be the name of the file.

Comment: Correction: That should be `datasets=sapply(csv_files, read.csv)` to assign the list to an object.

Comment: From `?Extract`: "The most important distinction between [, [[ and $ is that the [ can select more than one element whereas the other two select a single element." So `[` will always give you a _sublist_, whereas `[[` will give you a single element of a list.

Comment: May I ask why I have been down voted? Is creating "more complicated" data structure problem for R or I have chosen wrong way for tackle my goal or what is the problem? Please make statement. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @RichardScriven, @joran comments I've end up with following solution:

```
CSV_PATH="/home/wakatana/r/csv"
CSV_FILES <- list.files(pattern="*.csv");
DATASETS  <- vector("list", length(CSV_FILES))
names(DATASETS) <- CSV_FILES
for (i in 1:length(CSV_FILES)){
  message(CSV_FILES[i])
  full.csv.path = file.path(CSV_PATH, CSV_FILES[i])
  if (CSV_FILES[i] == "skip_first_four_lines.csv"){
    DATASETS[[i]] <- read.csv(file=full.csv.path, header=F, sep=",", skip=4, col.names = names(read.csv(file=full.csv.path, nrow = 0)))
  }
  else {
    DATASETS[[i]] <- read.csv(file=full.csv.path, header=T, sep=",", skip=0, check.names=TRUE)
  }
}
```

If somebody will show different approach and explain why it is better I will accept his question.